# making class iterable: Access violation reading location

Tags: c++

I have created a class called ring it works like that:

```
ring<std::string> example(2);
examples.add("one");
examples.add("two");
examples.add("three"); // this element will replace the first element
```

also, I have tried to make it iterable but it crashes with an exception Access violation reading location
the exception location is at cout in the main for loop
the program works very well without the for loop

the ring class:

```
template <class input>
class ring {
public:
    class iterator;

private:
    input* data;
    int size;
    int pos = 0;

public:
    ring(const int size) : size(size), data(NULL) { data = new input[size]; }

    ~ring() { delete[] data; }

    void add(input in) {
        if (pos == size)
            pos = 0;
        data[pos++] = in;
    }

    iterator begin() { return iterator(0, *this); }

    iterator end() { return iterator(size - 1, *this); }

    input& get(int i) { return data[i]; }
};
```

the iterator class:

```
template <class input>
class ring<input>::iterator {
private:
    int m_pos;
    ring m_ring;

public:
    iterator(int pos, ring& aRing) : m_pos(pos), m_ring(aRing) {}

    ~iterator() {}

    input& operator* () { return m_ring.get(m_pos); }

    bool operator!= (const iterator& other) const { return m_pos != other.m_pos; }

    iterator& operator++(int) {
        m_pos++;
        return *this;
    }

    iterator& operator++() {
        m_pos++;
        return *this;
    }
};
```

main:

```
int main() {
    ring<string> textring(3);

    textring.add("one");
    textring.add("two");
    textring.add("three");
    textring.add("four");

    for (auto text : textring) {
        cout << text << endl;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your program crashes because class `ring` doesn't implement [rule of three](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three). You should provide all copy operations.

What is the reason of crash?

In destructor the same memory is deleted twice due to shallow copy. This copy is made by `begin`/`end` which returns iterator in which you make copy of `ring`.

Quick solution, is to store `ring` inside iterator as reference:

```
template <class input>
class ring<input>::iterator {
private:
    int m_pos;
    ring& m_ring;
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4584c99fbe0c3f06)